# Model data not showing?

Tags: model-view-controller, ember.js, ember-data, ember-cli

I have this sort of action in my controller

```
action : {
    search: function(){
        this.store.find('vehicle')
    } 
}
```

now when i try to pressed the button the data successfully return in store.
but when i try to loop the data is not appearing

```
{{#each foo as |bar|}} 
    {{bar.data}} 
{{/each}}
```

Comment: Where is the button / action being used? Also - Pretty sure you're missing an s on that  `actions` - and that you need to return it - and get it added to foo somehow.

Comment: its still not working my final thoughts on this. is the handlebars is not gonna work unless you preload your data before the handelbar trigger

Answer (score 0):

You are missing return in action.

```
actions: {
    search(){
        return this.get('store').find('vehicle');
    } 
}
```

Comment: even i use return the data is not inserting into dom